# Core Data mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification Performance

Tags: core-data

I am importing large amounts of data on a background queue. Each `Route` has few thousand `Location`s.

I am importing on a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

In the following method I am getting every object I created i.e. Routes and Locations.

```
- (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification*) notification
```

This means that I have a huge number of objects that need to be `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`ed on the main thread although, initially, I only need the Routes and possible not even those.

How can I skip merging objects when they are of no interest, such as when no fetch request has yet been made?

How can I merge just the `Route`s and when I need the `Location`s let them be lazy loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a parent/child design, you do not need to consume those notifications.  Those notifications should only be used when you are dealing with two contexts that are not connected.

If you are not using a parent/child design, I recommend changing it over to thats design to eliminate this bottleneck.

You will still have main thread usage during the merge but it will be dramatically improved.

Comment: Can you please qualify why "it will be dramatically improved"?

Comment: Because the notification is used to notify one context about changes from another. That involves loading the object twice and comparing data.  That is expensive.  When the contexts are parent/child the notifications are consumed internally to Core Data, the objects are already fetched, it is more of just some pointer math instead of compares.  It is a significant improvement to the older notification consumption design that you are using currently.

Comment: OK, good point. However, what I am trying to do is skip the main context if it is not necessary. If I didn't merge at all I would achieve this, but I would not see newly imported objects in my NSFetchedResultsControllers. If I don't have any NSFetchedResultsController interested in these objects then it wouldn't mater.

Comment: If you set up a parent/child you won't need to skip the main context at all.  The performance improvements should eliminate the need to try and dance around the main context.  However, with all things, you need to keep your locking of the PSC down to a minimum so frequent saves will be a big benefit.

Answer (score 0):

```
[mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification]
```

In the example above `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` hits the main thread if the imported objects have been registered in the main context already. This could happen if a `NSFetchedResultsControllers` is fetching all results.

Marcus explains in the comments of his answer why registered objects are saved faster using a child context.

If the imported object **have not been registered** in the main context (faulted relationships for example) then the performance is really good. Up to ten times faster than using a child context to import. This situation is quite likely if you are importing relationships.